# Can I direct Apache Beam late data into another output?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

Is it possible to route late data into another output instead of dropping it? I see that Flink supports this - [getting late data as a side output](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/windows/#getting-late-data-as-a-side-output).

Answer (score 0):

You can update a Beam pipeline to not drop late data by specifying [Window.withAllowedLateness](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#managing-late-data).

This data can be processed or pushed to a different output using a subsequent `ParDo` transform.